# How to combine two separate results which are similar into one combined result

Tags: mysql, sql

> I'm building a version system where phones will be able to sync with
>   the server.For example the phone runs on the version 1 and the server
>   has the version 2, so it means that the server will just return the
>   data for version 2.

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `exercise` (
  `id_exercise` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `exercise_audit` (
  `id_exercise_audit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name will take the new value if inserted ,or the old value if edited.And the latest value if deleted.',
  `action_peformed` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reference_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `change_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `version` (
  `id_version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `state` enum('C','P') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The exercise table has 3 different triggers so that it can handle the exercise_audit table.

The current response that i have with the following query

```
SELECT ea.action_peformed,
    ea.version,
    ea.change_date,
    e.name,
    e.id_exercise 
FROM exercise_audit AS ea 
LEFT JOIN exercise AS e 
ON e.id_exercise = ea.reference_id 
WHERE version > :version
```

looks as like this:

```
[
{
    "action_peformed": "insert",
    "version": "1",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:42:03",
    "audit_name": "Push Ups",
    "current_name": "Push Ups",
    "id_exercise": "1"
},
{
    "action_peformed": "insert",
    "version": "1",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:42:06",
    "audit_name": "Squat",
    "current_name": "Squat",
    "id_exercise": "2"
},
{
    "action_peformed": "insert",
    "version": "1",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:42:09",
    "audit_name": "Chin Ups",
    "current_name": "Chin Ups",
    "id_exercise": "3"
},
{
    "action_peformed": "insert",
    "version": "2",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:44:25",
    "audit_name": "Pull Ups",
    "current_name": "Pull Ups",
    "id_exercise": "4"
},
{
    "action_peformed": "insert",
    "version": "2",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:45:08",
    "audit_name": "Sit Up",
    "current_name": "Sit Up",
    "id_exercise": "5"
},
{
    "action_peformed": "insert",
    "version": "2",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:45:28",
    "audit_name": "Pike Push Up",
    "current_name": "Pike Push Ups",
    "id_exercise": "6"
},
{
    "action_peformed": "update",
    "version": "3",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:47:28",
    "audit_name": "Pike Push Up",
    "current_name": "Pike Push Ups",
    "id_exercise": "6"
}
```

]

The problematic part is this one:

```
{
    "action_peformed": "insert",
    "version": "2",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:45:28",
    "audit_name": "Pike Push Up",
    "current_name": "Pike Push Ups",
    "id_exercise": "6"
},
{
    "action_peformed": "update",
    "version": "3",
    "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:47:28",
    "audit_name": "Pike Push Up",
    "current_name": "Pike Push Ups",
    "id_exercise": "6"
}
```

> NOTE! The reason why the name is same in both is because in insert the
>   name is NEW.name and in the update the name is OLD.name, so that i can
>   keep a track of the history data.

As you can see i have the same exercise with id_exercise of 6 and it was inserted in version 2 and updated in version 3.

And the question that i have is how to combine them in sql that it is as one.

For example to achieve the following:

```
{
        "action_peformed": "insert",
        "version": "3",
        "change_date": "2017-06-22 16:47:28",
        "audit_name": "Pike Push Up",
        "current_name": "Pike Push Ups",
        "id_exercise": "6"
    }
```

That it combines the update and insert so that it uses the last updated data to be as the insert data.

The reason why is if the user has version 1 on the mobile device, and he didn't sync with the web for a while.And the web has the version of 6 for example ,and an exercise has been added in version 3 and it has also been updated in version 6.So when the phone requests the data that it does't do insert and update on the same thing.Instead to combine it into one thing which will have the latest value as insert instead of update.

I could solve it with some php code but it would complicate it self out....

Comment: Why not return the data from the exercise table instead of the audit table. That way the output is the current data, and you can ignore update/insert audit records. Just use the audit table to determine if there is an update after the last update date for the user.

Comment: I mix the output between both of them.Read my question one more time you will see why i need to mix them.Its because of syncing with the phone so that it can keep track of which data the user has on the phone and which not.

Comment: I taught of using GROUP BY... than to check if its bigger than 1 and to take the last value from it and to place insert instead of update.That it could be done but still I'm not sure if its the right way thats why I have asked here @sloanthrasher.

Comment: The phone gets json with the list of changes that need to be done {insert:[....],update:[.....]} etc thats why i need to mix them out

Comment: The group by could work, just use max on version and change_date. A GROUP_CONCAT could be used on the action_performed column, and an if to see if there's an "insert" value to determine the value of action_performed in the output.

Comment: Write it as an answer if it runs better than mine I'l accept it :D I'l write mine and add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what determines the value for action_performed, so that part is a guess.

```
SELECT IF('insert' IN GROUP_CONCAT(ea.`action_peformed`),'insert','update') as `action_performed`,
    MAX(ea.`version`) as `version`,
    MAX(ea.`change_date`) as `change_date`,
    e.`name`,
    e.`id_exercise` 
FROM `exercise_audit` AS ea 
LEFT JOIN `exercise` AS e 
ON e.`id_exercise` = ea.`reference_id` 
WHERE `version` > :version
GROUP BY e.`id_exercise`
```